# what service to restart for /var/log/auth.log to start

Tags: linux, log-files, ubuntu-10.04

Here is a situation since the log files on my server had grown to several Gigabytes I took a backup of directory /var/log and then manually when to each subdirectory of /var/log and the files which were big in size I did

```
 cat > /var/log/file_which_is_big
```

press 2 times enter key (basically over wrote those files with a blank space) and then

```
Ctrl+C
```

So basically I over wrote those files to be blank.

Now when I open /var/log/auth.log I don't see any entry (which is expected also since I over wrote) but when I exit the SSH session and login again then also I do not see any entry in auth.log is there any way other than rebooting the machine to make sure I keep getting the entries in /var/log/auth.log I am not sure which service writes in this file.

This is a Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. restart rsyslog:

   $sudo service rsyslog restart
2. Use echo, then not have to restart rsyslog

   $sudo echo -n > /var/log/file_which_is_big

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 10.04

```
sudo service syslog-ng restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the syslog service writes to this file, as well as a number of others.

Check the file `/etc/syslog.conf` to see which services are logged to which file (it's not a very complex file, but it should have its own man page if you want some explanation).  Provided you're sure that `/var/log/auth.log` is listed there, and provided you're sure the file exists (sys won't create a file, only append to it) then

```
/etc/init.d/syslog restart
```

should ensure that file gets logged to.

Edit: I collided with alvosu's answer above, and I defer to him in picking rsyslog not syslog.  I'm a red hat guy, and they're still using syslog.